# CSS: Vertical centered text with one fixed-width container and fluid text length

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I'm having trouble finding the right solution for this fully fluid layout. I want the Sub-title in the following fiddles to be vertically center aligned next to the icon. The Sub-title may break onto multiple lines depending on the size of the browser (and varying length of text).

I have two fiddles prepared - the first attempt is my preferred approach as I've more thoroughly tested similar layouts:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmDFC/

The second fiddle, is an attempt on the same situation using `display:table-cell;`, but for the life of me I couldn't fix up the lost right text alignment, and I've also never thoroughly tested IE6+ compat with this display type:

http://jsfiddle.net/mmDFC/1/  (this almost works, save the loss of `text-align:right;`)

I have looked up a host of similarly titled SO questions but couldn't find what I wanted, so great answer points me to one I've missed, or come up with a solution to the above.

All in the name of vertical aligned text... :/

---

Browser update: I fiddled in Chrome, I see IE8 behaves similarly, but Ffox3 behaves differently for solution 2.

Comment: Can you clarify the question? What do you want vertically centered? If it's .icon, it looks right for me (Chrome 14)

Comment: The text, vertically aligned when on one line or two (sorry, that info is part of the fiddle). You may have to stretch the fiddle quite a bit to see the loss of right alignment with solution 2. the icon, at the moment, will look centered because it is providing height to the container.

Comment: Ah, i see now. Make sure you provide this information in the actual question itself.

Comment: in your fiddle, does h2's height have to vary? Or can it be fixed? If fixed; I think i have a solution.

Comment: It must vary, because the length of the title will vary, as will the width of the screen. I tried setting 'min-height' on solution #2 but that only accepted a height value seemingly. But yes, it must vary, but go ahead and post your solution because it still may work out well enough to use (I'ma hoping anyway!). Cheers Thomas.

Comment: Phooey. I thought it worked, but... it didn't. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Much appreciated - yeah, I'm still feeling the same after a coffee and a break outside :P

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/WecP4/10/) demonstrates a table-like behavior - with fluid and fixed "cells". That's half the answer, sort of. If I get the vertical alignment part working I'll post an answer with both in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you want right, you just need to add `display:table` to the `h2`

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <h1>Main Title</h1>
    <h2>
        <span id="fluid">
            Fluid Span
        </span>
        <span id="icon">
            Lots of long text...
        </span>

    </h2>
</div>

.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both; 
}
h2 {
    float:right;  
    text-align:right; 
    background-color:#999;
    display:table;
    width:43%;
}
span {
    background-color:#ccc;   
    border:1px #000 solid;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
span#fluid {
    display:table-cell;

    height:100%;

}

span#icon { 
    display:table-cell;
    width:60px;
    height:40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/WecP4/28/

Let me know if this isn't what you want.

Comment: It's almost there, in fact it does the trick in IE8, Chrome, Ffox, Opera, Safari - but IE6 and 7 don't seem to have a clue - everything is displayed as though inline. I think I'm going to use this and provide fallbacks for IE6/7. I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if you or anyone else can provide any clues on how to do the vertical alignment in IE6/7. Thanks for your help so far Thomas :D

Comment: Ok, added it in - and to fix the loss of right-alignment I added margin-left:auto; to the tablefied H2 element. IE6/7 got a rough-shod positioning approach which doesn't center vertically all the time - but too bad!

Comment: @Danjah ack, sorry to be so late in replying. Glad you got it figured out. :)